# Proper use of return error code on Exit

Tags: c++, c

For C/C++ applications in Windows(non GUI), what should be the proper list of error codes for different failures? I have seen various lists such as from IBM and others, but I was wondering if there was some consensus on typical error codes given to the user when the program exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three portable values for the argument to `exit`: `0`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and `EXIT_SUCCESS`. `0` is equivalent to `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: The standard (of C at least), doesn't tell anything about return value of `0` and its relation with `EXIT_SUCCESS` (as far as I recall). Can you refer to the standard?

Comment: They're not necessarily equal, @Shahbaz, although they are equivalent. That is, passing either one to `exit` causes the program to return an "implementation-defined form of the status *successful termination*." (7.20.4.3/5) The simplest way to ensure that happens would be to make the values equal, but it's possible that `exit` could be implemented to recognize multiple designated "success" values (i.e., both zero and whatever `EXIT_SUCCESS` expands to).

Comment: @RobKennedy, right. I had missed the zero in "If the value of status is **zero** or EXIT_SUCCESS"

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/EXIT_SUCCESS/

for success exit from program:

```
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

for failure exit from program:

```
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errorlevel#DOS):

> Apart from the macros EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE, the C standard
>   does not define the meaning of return codes. Rules for the use of
>   return codes vary on different platforms (see the platform-specific
>   sections).

In the wikipedia:

> **DOS**
>
> In DOS terminology, an errorlevel is an integer exit code returned by
>   an executable program or subroutine. Errorlevels typically range from
>   0 to 255. In DOS there are only 256 error codes available.
>
> **Windows**
>
> Windows uses 32-bit signed integers as exit codes.[9] If a process
>   fails initialization, a Windows system error code may be returned.[10]
>   Windows system error codes are available online.[11]
>
> Exit codes are directly referenced, for example, by the command line
>   interpreter CMD.exe in the errorlevel terminology inherited from DOS.
>   .NET Framework processes and the Windows PowerShell refer to it as the
>   ExitCode property of the Process object.

According to wikipedia, The following [link](http://www.hiteksoftware.com/mize/Knowledge/articles/049.htm) contains the error codes related to the windows platform

Comment: jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any such standards as far as I know. The only standard is to return EXIT_SUCCESS (from stdlib.h) in case it's a successful return. This helps scripts which call your program check for success. The error codes you return need to be well documented for your program. POSIX recommends returning between 0-255 from main. Usually 0 is EXIT_SUCCESS.

If you have only one particular failure return you can use EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: Re: "Usually `0` is `EXIT_SUCCESS`": on every conforming implementation `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` **both** can be used to indicate success.